# Create a global timer to run in background in swift

Tags: swift, timer, background

In my app there is a option for sending otp. Once I send otp a timer will run.i want to run the time till the time completed even if I will go to any other viewcontroller. Means when I will come to this otp screen again the timer will be running if the time is not completed.so the timer will be a global timer and can be run in background.

```
 @IBAction func resendOtpButtonWasPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
  timerLabel.text = "120"
       
        sender.isEnabled = false
        sendSmsAgainLabel.isHidden = false
        timerLabel.isHidden = false
        self.timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 1.0, repeats: true, block: { (timer) in
            self.counter -= 1
            
            self.updateTimerLabel(count: self.counter)
        })

        
    }

func updateTimerLabel(count: Int){
        if count > 0{
            timerLabel.text = "\(count)"
//            resendOtpButon.setTitle("ResendOtp in: \(count)", for: .normal)
        }
        else{
            timer.invalidate()
            self.counter = 120
            timerLabel.isHidden = true
            sendSmsAgainLabel.isHidden = true
            resendOtpButon.isEnabled = true

        }
        
    }
```